# How do I count the frequency of a value in a data frame based on a factor level in R?

Tags: r, plyr, factors

I have a Legal dataset in which all columns are represented by factors

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2101 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ specialty: Factor w/ 5 levels "Real Estate",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ col1     : Factor w/ 161 levels "10060","11404",..: 95 40 72 52 72 72 72 161 161 161 ...
 $ col2     : Factor w/ 138 levels "0277T","11602",..: 63 18 76 29 138 50 138 138 138 138 ...
 $ col3     : Factor w/ 106 levels "10061","10160",..: 44 58 106 51 106 58 106 106 106 106 ...
```

Columns 1-3 consist of 5-digit codes which correspond to a specific legal procedure. Codes can repeat within the same column and across different columns. Codes are organized as factors. I am interested in getting the frequencies of a set of 7 codes, `[49585, 44310, 44320, 38564, 44125, 44150, 49419]`

```
> head(df)
   specialty   col1  col2  col3
1 Bankruptcy  49585 49000 44950
2 Tort        44140 38564 49255
3 Real Estate 49000 49419  NULL
4 Bankruptcy  44310 44120 49000
5 Real Estate 49000  NULL  NULL
6 Tort        49000 44950 49255
```

However, I only want to get frequencies of those codes when they are associated with two specific levels in the specialty column: `"Tort"` and `"Real Estate"`. This is tricky due to the presence of factors. How do I find the counts of each code in the set only when they also occur within the same row as either of the levels mentioned?

Expected Output:

```
**Counts**        49585  44310  44320  38564  44125  44150  49419
Tort                 12    230    232      1     21      2     23
Real Estate         280     50     40     92    121     12    726
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need

```
df1 <- subset(df, specialty %in% c('Real Estate', 'Tort'))
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(df1, id.var='specialty')[,-2]
dM[] <- lapply(dM, factor)
table(dM)
#             value
#specialty     38564 44140 44950 49000 49255 49419 NULL
# Real Estate     0     0     0     2     0     1    3
# Tort            1     1     1     1     2     0    0
```

Or

```
res <- recast(df1, id.var='specialty', specialty~value, length)
res 
#    specialty 38564 44140 44950 49000 49255 49419 NULL
#1 Real Estate     0     0     0     2     0     1    3
#2        Tort     1     1     1     1     2     0    0

res[c(TRUE,!colSums(!res[-1]))]
#    specialty 49000
#1 Real Estate     2
#2        Tort     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(specialty = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Bankruptcy", "Real Estate", "Tort"), class = "factor"), 
col1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("44140", 
"44310", "49000", "49585"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("38564", "44120", "44950", 
"49000", "49419", "NULL"), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("44950", "49000", "49255", 
"NULL"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("specialty", "col1", 
"col2", "col3"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. How do I limit the output to the set of desired codes though?

Comment: @JasonMatney You can use `subset` to limit the set of desired codes.  Based on the example provided, I think you may get only 49000.  Is that what you meant?